# Angular Break, Migration to 4.1.3

Tags: angular, dom, webpack

I am reworking one of our angular services in the midst of an update to angular 4.1.3

We used BroweserDomAdapter before but that has seen been deprecated by the angular team, and I am struggling to figure out what the issue is after rewriting it.

What am I doing wrong:

```
import { Injectable }        from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Title }             from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserDomAdapter } from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';

@Injectable()
export class SeoService {
/**
 * Angular 2 Title Service
 */

/**
 * <head> Element of the HTML document
 */
private headElement: HTMLElement;
/**
 * <meta name="description"> Element of the document head
 */
private metaDescription: HTMLElement;
/**
 * <meta name="robots"> Element of the document head
 */
private robots: HTMLElement;
dom:any;
/**
 * Inject the Angular 2 Title Service
 * @param titleService
 */
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private titleService: Title){
    this.titleService = titleService;

    /**
     * get the <head> Element
     * @type {any}
     */
    this.dom = document;

    this.headElement = this.dom.getSelection('head');
    this.metaDescription = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('description');
    this.robots = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('robots');
}

public getTitle(): string {
    return this.titleService.getTitle();
}

public setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle + ' | Stareable');
}

public getMetaDescription(): string {
    return this.metaDescription.getAttribute('content');
}

public setMetaDescription(description: string) {
    this.metaDescription.setAttribute('content', description);
}

public getMetaRobots(): string {
    return this.robots.getAttribute('content');
}

public setMetaRobots(robots: string) {
    this.robots.setAttribute('content', robots);
}

/**
 * get the HTML Element when it is in the markup, or create it.
 * @param name
 * @returns {HTMLElement}
 */
private getOrCreateMetaElement(name: string): HTMLElement {
    let el: HTMLElement;
    el = this.dom.getSelection('meta[name=' + name + ']');
    if (el === null) {
        el = this.dom.createElement('meta');
        el.setAttribute('name', name);
        this.headElement.appendChild(el);
    }
    return el;
  }
 }
```

Here is the error in console:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.titleService.setTitle is not a function
TypeError: this.titleService.setTitle is not a function
    at SeoService.setTitle

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix your constructor:

```
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private titleService: Title){

    /**
     * get the <head> Element
     * @type {any}
     */
    this.dom = document;

    this.headElement = this.dom.getSelection('head');
    this.metaDescription = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('description');
    this.robots = this.getOrCreateMetaElement('robots');
}
```

declaring private params in your constructor are visible for the whole component.

Comment: Now getting: this.metaDescription.setAttribute is not a function

Comment: How do I refactor getOrCreateMetaElement();?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the "getSelection" methods for the native javascript function:

```
this.headElement = this.dom.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

and:

```
el = this.dom.querySelector("meta[name=\'"+ name + "\']");
```

After that everything worked again.